# I can't convert binary using this method in javascript but it works in java

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="inpt" value="please input text in here" id="text_field"></input> <button id="btn" onClick="bnry()">Click me!</button>
        <p id="yo"></p>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function hello(){
            var n = document.getElementById('text_field').value;
            if(n == "fd"){
                document.getElementById('yo').innerHTML = "pass unlock";
            }
        }
        function bnry(){
            var ary = new Array();
            var num = document.getElementById('text_field').value;
            var count = 1;
            while (num < num*2){
                count = num % 2;
                num = num / 2;
                ary.push(count);
             }
             document.getElementById("yo").innerHTML = ary; 
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Please describe the problem you are having accurately. If possible post a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: When will `num` ever not be less than `num * 2`? If you are relying on overflow or something, you might want `num < (num << 1)`.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers in JavaScript are only floating point. In Java the above works because the `/` operator applied on integers returns an integer:

```
5/2 == 2 // Java
5/2 == 2.5 // Javascript
```

To fix this, use `Math.floor` to convert to integer:

```
 while (num > 0){
     count = num % 2;
     num = Math.floor(num / 2);
     ary.push(count);
 }
```

Comment: The only time that `num < num*2` is true is when `num <= 0`, so since num will never become negative, you can use `while (num)` or `while (num > 0)` etc.